# Math logic between camera angle and lens

Tags: camera

Camera has two properties:

```
bpy.data.objects['Camera'].data.angle
bpy.data.objects['Camera'].data.lens
```

If change one value, the other one will be changed automatically.
I am curious about the math logic.

From the table below:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{angle }(\theta)&\text{lens}\\
\hline
30^\circ&-18.691732\\
45^\circ&28.681456\\
60^\circ&2.497919
\end{array}
$$

Sounds like the formula is: $\text{lens}=\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$, but what's the theory come from. I found a diagram about camera as below but not figure out how to match this formula with this diagram:

Is this logic specific to blender or it's generic for all camera's?

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92204/7777

Comment: thanks, so that means half_the_diagonal_of_sensor  equal to 16mm, diagonal sensor is 32mm.is it specific to blender?

Answer (score 2):

The angle of view for a **rectilinear** projection camera is calculated by:

$$a=2\arctan{\frac{d}{2f}}$$

$a$**:** angle of view
$d$**:** dimension of the sensor (horizontal or vertical)
$f$**:** effective focal length

horizontal and vertical angle of view differ if your camera sensor is not a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks, so d should equal to 32mm, then half d is 16mm always.

Comment: @J.Doe is there math I could use to change from a rectilinear view to an Equirectangular view or the other way around? trying to morph the camera from one type to another.

Comment: hmm ther shour is... But sry i have no idea. Maybe search for Little Planet? Let me know here if you find sth! i would be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

the relationship as below diagram:

[image]