# Viewport lens setting to match Unreal 4 editor fov?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

Just wondering what 'Lens' setting should I set to make Blender's 3d view fov match Unreal 4's fov?

Blender says something about 'focal lens angle' in the 'Lens' tooltip, which is not focal length, right?

Comment: check the last paragraph of this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92204/7777